# Modify HTML based on h3 date and associated list items

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am very new to Python and can't figure this one out.

I would like to have a script that does the following:

1. Reads my HTML file
2. Finds any dates in the h3 tag that are yesterday or earlier
3. Removes everything that is not relevant

Any insight is greatly appreciated - I've messed around with BeautifulSoup but am not sure I have the regex chops or knowledge to put it all together.

Here is my attempt, which successfully removes yesterday's date between the h3 tags, but I don't know how to deal with list items of varying lengths that are associated with the preceding h3 tag.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# parse html
h = '''
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>reprex</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>05/20/2022</h3>
<ul>
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>banana</li>
    <li>cabbage</li>
</ul>

<h3>05/21/2022</h3>
<ul>
    <li>doritos</li>
    <li>eclairs</li>
    <li>fritos</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(h, 'html.parser')

# get yesterday's date
yesterday = (datetime.today() - timedelta(days = 1)).strftime('%m/%d/%Y') 

yesterday = str("<h3>" + yesterday + "</h3>")

soup = BeautifulSoup(str(soup).replace(yesterday, ""))
```

Desired output:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>reprex</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>05/21/2022</h3>
<ul>
    <li>doritos</li>
    <li>eclairs</li>
    <li>fritos</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of BeautifulSoup, an HTML Parser, is to use its parsing capabilities and not .replace() on raw text.

So:

**let's find all the `<h3>` tags, and for each that's irrelevant, destroy it, find its adjacent `<ul>` and destroy it as well.**

**using .decompose() we can destroy elements**

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# parse html
h = '''
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>reprex</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>05/20/2022</h3>
<ul>
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>banana</li>
    <li>cabbage</li>
</ul>

<h3>05/21/2022</h3>
<ul>
    <li>doritos</li>
    <li>eclairs</li>
    <li>fritos</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(h, 'html.parser')

today_midnight = datetime.combine(datetime.now(), time.min)  # Start of day

for el in soup.find_all("h3"): 
    date = el.text

   
    date = datetime.strptime(date,'%m/%d/%Y') 
    if date < today_midnight: 
        el.find_next_sibling('ul').decompose()
        el.decompose()
        

print (soup) # or soup.prettify() but that doesn't look so good.
```

to test stuff like this out i like to use random.randint

```
if random.randint(0,1)==1: 
        el.find_next_sibling('ul').decompose()
        el.decompose()
```